# Does running OS from bootable drive use half of the system RAM?

Tags: kali-linux

I'm going to make a bootable kali linux with persistence. So I want to know if running live OS from USB drive uses half of my system RAM?
And if there's any better option than running from USB, let me know.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

The Live USB use RAM like a normal OS, the only change is that you HDD is a USB, then the speed of OS depends of USB speed connection. Responding to you answer, yes, it use RAM

Comment: As you know that when we have two OS in 1 PC (say ubuntu and windows) and we are working on any one of them, then the OS uses only half of our PC RAM. So my question is same for the USB boot. If I have 4GB of RAM in my PC then what % of it will be used by my USB boot?

Comment: You RAM only is used by one OS, the OS booting in that moment. So if you boot for example ubuntu, this have all RAM avalible on hardware, the 100%